# Today-Widget "Unable to load" error

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

From time to time widget crashing with "unable to load" error. 
Is anyone know how to fix it? 
Widget haven't requests to server or smth else.

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Unable to load** in **today extension** mostly appears when:

1. You extension crash due to some reason
2. It takes more memory than what is provided by the system. **(Memory Limit : max 16MB approx.)**

Debug your app extension to find out the exact problem.

Refer to Xcode's **Debug Gauge** for Memory and CPU utilization.

**Edit:**

**Debugging today extension**

You can debug your extension the same way you debug your main project. Just select that particular `target scheme` in your Xcode and run the project.

[image]

Now try using the breakpoints and other print statements in the extension’s code and you are good to go. Happy coding..

Comment: Second part was my problem. Just removed a few images and it's work properly.

Comment: Please let me know how to debug the Widget?

Comment: @iDev750 I've updated the answer for debugging the widget.

Comment: @PGDev Thank you and I have solved my problem. Actually, I was getting crashed because UIImageView was unable to find the image which was I'm using.
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

**REBOOT** the device.
This saved me.

Comment: Thank you for this tip! Was very helpful in addition to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this error 
I used a custom view. But forgot to check Is initial viewController.
Set an entry point form "show attribute inspector" as an initial view controller

Answer (score 1):

1. I have faced the same issue where it wasn't showing anything. Even my debug option was not working. I found an article online which helped me a lot. I would like to recommend this here.
2. Most of the time it is the size of the content view that crashes the widget. in that case, use this code snippet in TodayViewController.

**Code snippet**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    var currentSize: CGSize = self.preferredContentSize
    currentSize.height = 200.0
    self.preferredContentSize = currentSize
}
```

[Link](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_8_Today_Extension_Widget_Tutorial) for further research.

Answer (score 0):

#### Make sure you have more than 0 rows

I have built a today-widget similar to [Building a Simple Widget for the Today View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/notificationcenter/building_a_simple_widget_for_the_today_view).

I had none of the above issues. Mine was 0 row (I had no data for this particular day and hence, 0 row). I did not expect that it could be the problem since in the main-app, you can have empty table-view.

If you see `unable to load` message, make sure you have at least 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Set this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case `NotificationCenter.framework` was accidentally deleted from `Link Binary With Libraries` in `Build Phases` tab in widget target.